# Error while insert into hive table using rand() function

Tags: hive

I tried below snippet  to insert random values in fileid column.
I got error like
//cannot recognize input near `'AS' 'floor' '(' in selection target)`//
Can anyone help me out .

```
Select floor(RAND()*(99999-10000)+10000); //works fine though.
```

I only got issue at insert time.

```
INSERT INTO table test.a1
SELECT
Fileid AS floor(RAND()*(99999-10000)+10000)
FROM
test.a2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up alias with column ref.
It should be:

```
INSERT INTO table test.a1
SELECT
Floor(RAND()*(99999-10000)+10000) as fileid
FROM
test.a2;
```

Comment: Thanks :]] @Grzegorz Skibinski